# exception:Row provided already belongs to a DataGridView control

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datarowcollection

I am getting following exception while coping the row in same datagrid view control
**System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message="Row provided already belongs to a DataGridView control."**
   Following is copy method that copies selected rows in in **currentRowCollection as DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection**

```
copy()
     {
            If (DataGridViewWorkGroupDetails.Rows.Count = 1) Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Try
                pasteMode = "copy"
                currentRowCollection = DataGridViewWorkGroupDetails.SelectedRows
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "frmworkgroup:copyRowCollectionError")
            End Try
       }
```

And in paste method

```
paste()
{
  Dim row As DataGridViewRow
  Dim myRow As DataGridViewRow
        For Each row In currentRowCollection
            myRow = row
            myRow.Cells.Item(1).Value = String.Empty
            DataGridViewWorkGroupDetails.Rows.Insert(DataGridViewWorkGroupDetails.Rows.Count - 1, myRow)
        Next

}
```

During paste in paste method i want to remain 1th column as empty string ..
     When I copy the row from one datagridview to another it works but when I copy to same datagridview then it adds exception.**Row provided already belongs to a DataGridView control**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using a reference to a datarow. The row in

```
For Each row In currentRowCollection
```

is actually a reference to the row that already exists in the dataview.

You need to do a deep copy of the data in the row before you call the insert.

```
myRow = DataGridViewWorkGroupDetails.NewRow();
myRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
DataGridViewWorkGroupDetails.Rows.Add(myRow);
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should work

Comment: its not working in vb.net ..There is no NewRow() method for the datagridview which used in the line above for
           myRow = DataGridViewWorkGroupDetails.NewRow();